# React form CSRF security

Tags: reactjs, security, jwt, token

I have a contact form created by React in my website. It is open to public and does not require people login. Within my website, I have implemented JWT token for those API endpoint required people login. With those API required people login, I will have a token after people login and then attch a JWT token with each API request. However, because this form is open to public, does not require user login, I cannot attch a token from login for CSRF. How can I make the form request secure?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you may be interested to read about similar question here: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/do-i-need-csrf-token-if-im-using-bearer-jwt

Long story short:

CSRF tokens (actually anti-CSRF tokens) were designed to deal with a problem of user session being held in a cookie. A cookie is always automatically attached to every request your browser makes. This was a problem, when you accessed malicious site that manufactured request to a site you were already logged into.

If you attach a JWT token with your own logic to every separate request, you are as good as fine and don't need additional tokens to prevent CSRF.

Comment: Well, my question is for the form open to public and do not login required. What you said does not suit my scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I seem to have misunderstood. If the endpoint is public, why do you want to protect it from CSRF then? Does it make sense?

Comment: That's my question... How can I make a form secure if I cannot have a token from login?

Comment: You can't. Public data is usually immutable and no one makes here any changes without authentication. You don't need CSRF protection if things are immutable.